# Show this is a tautology without using a truth table

Tags: logic, assignment-problem

I am doing a homework assignment and I've been stuck on this question for a long time now. The question says to prove this equation is a tautology without using a truth table. I assume we have to use equivalences to do this but I can't figure out how to do this.

The equation is:

```
[⌐p AND (p OR q)] → q
```

Please help me!!

EDIT:
The equivalences I know are associative, distributive, DeMorgan, absorption, negation, contraposition, implication elimination, and biconditional elimination.  I can use ANY equivalence as long as I can show how I got it.

Comment: Remember that AND is distributive. The rest is just a cleanup.

Comment: This is NOT an answer. This tautology actually says that: 
A common approach to proving that either $p$ or $q$ is valid is to assume first $\lnot p$ (or $\lnot q$) and then prove $q$ (or $p$).

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you CAN use. Have you learned the laws of propositional logic (de Morgan, distributivity,..)?

Comment: I don't get it. How is this a tautology? p=true and q=false yields false... Edit: by reading the answers, it seems like a NOT has disappeared from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the axiomatic system(I guess this is the name in english, not north-american natural here).

When you have 'something $\rightarrow$ anotherthing', you can separate then and think like this:

You have this hypothesis: $¬p \ and \ (p\ or\ q)$

And you can use some rules to derivate $q$ from that.

The main rule you want to use is called $modus\ ponens$, this rules says that, if you have a $p$ and a $p \rightarrow q$, then that is the same as $q$.

Another useful rule is $modus\ tollens$, this rule says, if you have $p \rightarrow q\ and\ ¬q$, then that is the same as $¬p$.

You can use also some equivalences, like, $p\ or\ q$, is the same of $¬p \rightarrow q$(just do the truth table and you'll see that is true), so, there are also alot of others equivalences and rules, but you'll see that at the right time, for now, those are enough to solve your problem.

Back to your problem: $¬p\ and\ (p\ or\ q) \rightarrow q$:

Do the following transformations:

1. $[¬p\ and\ (¬p \rightarrow q)]$ (equivalence from 'or' to '->' in the second term)
2. $Modus\ Ponens$ applied over $[¬p\ and\ (¬p \rightarrow q)]$ gives you $q$, because the rules says, if you have a $p\ and\ p\rightarrow q$ that is the same as $q$
3. then you transformed $[¬p\ and\ (¬p \rightarrow q)]$ to $q$

Now you have $q \rightarrow q$, and that, is for sure, a tautology.

In step 2, I applied $Modus\ Ponens$ over $¬p$ instead of $p$, and I can do that, because if you look very carefully, the $p$ from the rule is different from your $p$, so, in other means, I can call your $¬p$ of a new name, like, $a$, and substitute in the rule and get $[a\ and\ (a \rightarrow q)]$, and that is exactly in the format the $modus\ ponens$ rule says.

I know, that can be alot of things to assimilate now, but once you finish your logic class, this will be natural to you!

Any further doubts, just ask!

Comment: thanks for the response, the only question I have is when you say " [¬p and (¬p→q)] gives you q " in step 2, I used a truth table to check that and I didn't get it to equal q.  What exactly did you do to get it to q?

Comment: Like I said, I used modus ponens

Comment: You must have done something wrong with you truth table, because the question itself already says that derivates q

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

(p → q) is equivalent to (⌐p + q)
AND is '.'
OR is '+'

```
  [⌐p AND (p OR q)] → q

  => (⌐p.p) + (⌐p.q) → q (Using distributive law)
  => (⌐p.q) → q
  => ⌐(⌐p.q) + q
  => p + ⌐q + q          (Using De-morgan's law) 
  => p + 1
  => 1
```